# Left Horizontal Alignment with ImportExcel after Conversion

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to add a left horizontal alignment for the whole of my Excel output after it has been converted from a text file to an Excel file using the ImportExcel module. Everything works in the script below, but each time I try to add what I think  is the right way to add the alignment it breaks. Any help would be appreciated.

See below code - I have tried using Set-ExcelRange to apply the alignment, but no luck so far.

```
$archiveFolderPath = Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "archive"
if (-not (Test-Path $archiveFolderPath)) { New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $archiveFolderPath | Out-Null }

Get-ChildItem $PSScriptRoot "*.txt" | ForEach-Object {
    $excelFilePath = Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "$($_.BaseName).xlsx"

    Get-Content $_.FullName | Where-Object { $_ -match '^\|.*\|$' } | ForEach-Object { $_.TrimStart('|') } |
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "|" | Export-Excel $excelFilePath -AutoSize -AutoFilter -BoldTopRow

    $timestamp = Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMdd-HHmm'
    $archiveFileName = "{0}_{1}.txt" -f $_.BaseName, $timestamp
    Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination (Join-Path $archiveFolderPath $archiveFileName)

    Write-Host "Txt file '$($_.FullName)' converted to Excel and moved to the archive as '$archiveFileName'."
}

Read-Host "Press enter to close."
```

Comment: You can use `Set-ExcelColumn` to change the horizontal alignment

Comment: Can you clarify which column are you looking to change the alignment ? Or all columns?

Comment: Hi Santiago, all columns please. I appreciate your help, I'm quite new to this! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `-PassThru` first to get an [`ExcelPackage`](https://epplussoftware.com/docs/5.3/api/OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.html), then from there you need to enumerate all columns in the package and pass them to `Set-ExcelColumn`. For instance, *this would be inside your loop*, you can do:

```bash
Get-ChildItem $PSScriptRoot '*.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    $excelFilePath = Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "$($_.BaseName).xlsx"

    $exportExcelSplat = @{
        AutoSize   = $true
        AutoFilter = $true
        BoldTopRow = $true
        PassThru   = $true
        Path       = $excelFilePath
    }

    $xlsx = Get-Content $_.FullName |
        Where-Object { $_ -match '^\|.*\|$' } |
        ForEach-Object { $_.TrimStart('|') } |
        ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter '|' |
        Export-Excel @exportExcelSplat

    # here you can loop over each worksheet or target a specific worksheet
    # and update the alignment of each column (this example would update all worksheets..)
    foreach ($wsheet in $xlsx.Workbook.Worksheets) {
        1..$wsheet.Dimension.Columns | ForEach-Object {
            $setExcelColumnSplat = @{
                HorizontalAlignment = 'Left'
                ExcelPackage        = $xlsx
                WorksheetName       = $wsheet.Name
                Column              = $_
            }

            Set-ExcelColumn @setExcelColumnSplat
        }
    }

    Close-ExcelPackage $xlsx
    # rest of your code here...
}
```

Comment: I'm not going to pretend to understand half of that, but it has allowed me to Left align all data in the worksheet. It sure takes a lot for such a simple thing it seems! Thank you.